# Bootstrap dropdown menu with select value from list

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I made one dropdown menu for a page, but my doubt is how I can keep it updatea value in a button from selected value. My code can update by one value but after select the dropdown menu stops works.

```js
        $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
            $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+'');
        });
```

```css
    .dropdown-menu 
    {
    width:  100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="dropdown">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                              Selecione uma especialidade
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="e01">Clinia da Dor</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="e02">Clinica de Neroendocrinologia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Psicologia da Saúde</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Epilepsia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Neurologia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Neurocirurgia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Neuropsicologia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica Psiquiatrica</a>

                                            </div>
                                          </div>
```

HTML

```js
<script>
        $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
            $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+'');
        });

    </script>
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                              Selecione uma especialidade
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="e01">Clinia da Dor</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" value="e02">Clinica de Neroendocrinologia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Psicologia da Saúde</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Epilepsia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Neurologia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Neurocirurgia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica de Neuropsicologia</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" type="button">Clinica Psiquiatrica</a>

                                            </div>
                                          </div>
```

How can I get the text value in button from dropdown menu with javascript.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Why did put your code twice? Which one should I check?

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem. Your first code seems to work properly.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is two imports colides and keeping work with error, already solved